# how do I output a list of strings that fall alphabetically between two input values

Tags: python

I'm given a text file called `input1.txt1` this file contains the following

```
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
philosophy
quadratics
transcript
wilderness
zoologists
```

Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file, followed by two strings representing the lower and upper bounds of a search range. The file should be read using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains a list of alphabetical, ten-letter strings, each on a separate line. Your program should output all strings from the list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds).

EX:

```
Enter the path and name of the input file: input1.txt
Enter the first word: ammunition
Enter the second word (it must come alphabetically after the first word): millennium
```

```
The words between ammunition and millennium are:
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

```py
file_to_open = input()
bound1 = input()
bound2 = input()

with open(file_to_open) as file_handle:
    list1 = [line.strip() for line in file_handle]

out = [x for x in list1 if x >= bound1 and x <= bound2]

out.sort()
print('\n'.join(map(str, out)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension with inequalities to check the string range:

```
out = [x for x in your_list if x >= 'ammunition' and x <= 'millennium']
```

This assumes that your range is *inclusive* on both ends, that is, you want to include `ammunition` and `millennium` on both ends of the range.

To further sort the `out` list and then write to a file, use:

```
out.sort()
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
text = '\n'.join(out)
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

Comment: @BoseongChoi I am not aware of comparison operator can be chained in Python :) Thanks.  IMHO both works and equally readable though :)

Comment: Oh I see but how would I then write those new values back into the file and display the output like it shows in the example? Do I have to create a new file? I can't just print out the list because each word in the list ends with a '\n' so it jumps to a new line every word

Answer (score 0):

if you should use readline() try this :

```
filepath = 'Iliad.txt'
start = 'sometxtstart'
end = 'sometxtend'
apending = False
out = ""
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        txt = line.strip()
        if(txt == end):
            apending = False
        if(apending):
            out+=txt + '\n'
        if(txt == start):
            apending = True               
        line = fp.readline()
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
file = input()
first = input()
second = input()


with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip('\n')
        if (l >= first) and (l <= second):
            print(line.strip())
        else:
            pass
```